# variable reference and manipulation from object to function in python

Tags: python, object

I have wrote following code in python

```
class check(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [1,2,3,4]
        self.b = 5
        appending(self.a, self.b)
        print "a", self.a
        print "b", self.b

def appending(a,b):
    a.append(5)
    b +=1
```

If now I run `check()` function, I got output as following:

```
a [1,2,3,4,5] [1,2,3,4,5]

b 5 5
```

So, I have following question

- Why it is that list(a) is got updated but not int(b)?
- It is related that I am modifying a but i am creating new object when I add 1 in b, in short, it is difference due to immutable or mutable data types.
- I have define self.a and self.b in object, i have define a,b in function, then why I can write print a and print b in object, get same output as self.a and self.b

Comment: I think `print "a", a` should be `print "a", self.a`, right?

Comment: Thanks , you are right

Comment: And the simple answer to your question is "yes". It's because the integer is immutable. `self.b` still points to the integer `5`. When you do `b += 1` you create a new integer and assign it to the identifier `b`, but only inside the scope of the function `appending`.

Answer (score 4):

`self.b` is a name for an integer `5`. The integer is an immutable object.

When you appear to mutate `b` you actually create a new object `6` and assign `b` as a name for it. This in no way affects the object `5` which `self.b` is a name for.

Answer (score 2):

Since a is a **list**, it's passed by reference to the method and any changed done to it within the method, will be done directly to the a.

Variable b is an integer, therefore it's passed by value and a copy of the variable is created to be used within the method. Any change will be visible only within the body of the method, but not to the "outside world".

Comment: This is incorrect. In python everything is passed by assignment. Here's an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/1977847

Comment: What is difference between passed by assignment and passed by reference or passed by value ?

I am little bit confused about this

Comment: reading this article should explain the difference: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Comment: Thanks you for guidance